# How to start learning about graphics in C++?

Tags: c++

I was learning console programming with C++ since a month online. I have completed the console one and wondering how those fantastic, beautiful softwares are made.

I tried to search on Google but I couldn't figure out anything. Is there any particular library or some header files are used for it or some kind of softwares are used?

Comment: If this is about game programming, have a look at https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/wiki/faq#wiki_getting_started. If this is about application programming, have a look at Qt and similar frameworks.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed for being too broad. You need a GUI library. Qt is a common choice.

Comment: Stack Overflow is better suited to more specific problems when programming.  Good luck and we'll see you soon.

Comment: You may try Qt, Gtk on Linux, or you can try to use MFC on Windows. But none of them are related to C++. You need a GUI lib.

Comment: I recommend learning about openGL. To understand what I am talking about, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968748/understanding-opengl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not have its own Graphics Library like languages like Java, However you can use OpenGL which is pretty good for 3D modelling, etc. If you want to make something like a GUI, use Qt.

Comment: with OpenGL you will also need an IDE. No more Emacs.

Comment: No, you can code for OpenGL with Emacs